# How to observe a specific combination of events?

Tags: c#, .net, events, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have multiple observables made with Rx's `FromEventPattern`, e.g.:

```
var a = Observable.FromEventPattern(...); // event A
var b = Observable.FromEventPattern(...); // event B
var c = Observable.FromEventPattern(...); // event C
```

How do I observe specific sequences of these events?

E.g., I want to observe the case when A then C happened, but without B in between, in a particular limited time frame.

Or: ABC then ABC then just B.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, elaborate please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
var query = a.Select(_ => c.TakeUntil(b)).Switch();
```

---

Would this work for the 5 second time period?

```
var query = a
    .Select(_ => c
        .TakeUntil(b)
        .TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))))
    .Switch();
```

Otherwise you'd need to look at the `Window` or `Join` operators.

Comment: Thanks, this looks cool, I'll experiment with it. Is there a way to limit it in time, e.g., `A -> [no B] -> C withing 5 secs`?

Comment: @avo - I've added an extra solution.